# SVN - User responsible for line in source file

Tags: svn, version-control

I pretty stuck with situation in which I need to get user responsible for specific file, line and revision. 
E.g. I have as input: source name, line number and revision. As output I need get user name.
I not so familiar with SVN and looking into documentation might take time (which I don't have).
In Clear Case it can be achieved by running this command:

```
cleartool annotate -nhe -fmt %u \t file_name.cpp
```

Answer (score 7):

```
svn blame
```

is what you are looking for

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html

Comment: Anton, thanks for this command. 
This command print content of file to stdout with revision number and user name responsible for line.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn ann -r revision_number source_name
```

Then go to line number in `svn` output

```
#svn help ann
blame (praise, annotate, ann): Output the content of specified files or
URLs with revision and author information in-line.
usage: blame TARGET[@REV]...

  If specified, REV determines in which revision the target is first
  looked up.

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
  -v [--verbose]           : print extra information
  -g [--use-merge-history] : use/display additional information from merge
                             history
  --incremental            : give output suitable for concatenation
  --xml                    : output in XML
  -x [--extensions] ARG    : Default: '-u'. When Subversion is invoking an
                             external diff program, ARG is simply passed along
                             to the program. But when Subversion is using its
                             default internal diff implementation, or when
                             Subversion is displaying blame annotations, ARG
                             could be any of the following:
                                -u (--unified):
                                   Output 3 lines of unified context.
                                -b (--ignore-space-change):
                                   Ignore changes in the amount of white space.
                                -w (--ignore-all-space):
                                   Ignore all white space.
                                --ignore-eol-style:
                                   Ignore changes in EOL style
                                -p (--show-c-function):
                                   Show C function name in diff output.
  --force                  : force operation to run

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
  --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting
  --config-dir ARG         : read user configuration files from directory ARG
```